# jQuery modal not interacting properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery modal that appears on top of an OpenLayers map.  When I try to control the modal,  it ignores the modal and controls the map.  I can only control the region which is outside of the map. How can I fix this problem?

Thanks!

```
function init_editor() {

$( '#widthColor' ).colorPicker();
$( '#fillColor').colorPicker();
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    value:1,
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    step: 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val(  ui.value );
    }
});

$( "#transparency" ).slider({
    value: 0.5,
    min: 0.1,
    max: 1,
    step: 0.1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#trans_val" ).val( ui.value );
    }
});

$( "#amount" ).val(  $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
$( "#trans_val" ).val(  $( "#transparency" ).slider( "value" ) );

//Map KML editor modal
var dlg = $( "#layer-manager" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            setColor( $('#widthColor').val(), $('#fillColor').val(), $('#amount').val(), $('#trans_val').val() );
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
}); 

//Register the modal
$(document).on("click", "a.layer-manager", function(e){
    $( "#layer-manager").dialog( "open" );
});
}
```

Also the site http://uganda.csrcdev.com/map/

Comment: At first glance i don't see anything obvioulsy wrong. However, what do you mean by "try to control the modal" and ff. ?

Comment: If the map if beneath the modal, when ever I click, scroll, etc, it controls the map instead. Here's the site if that's still unclear http://uganda.csrcdev.com/map/

Comment: I've been looking at your site, I just wasn't sure I understood your meaning, which I think I do now. However on your site I do not seem to be able (allowed ?) to popup the modal, even though I 'see' it on Firebug.

Comment: Sorry I should have included this: Click 'Albertine Rift' and you'll see another 'Albertine Rift'. Click on the cog next to it to open the modal. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:

```
function init_editor() {

$( "#layer-manager").css('z-index','1000');
```

Then the modal will be a top level element. Right now it is hiding behind everything else.

Open firebug and locate the dialog near the bottom. Then give it the `z-index: 1000;` to see it work before you make the change.